# Help in understanding best way to combine these 2 sentences

Tags: prepositions, sentence-combination

please  these 2 sentences need to be combined at the italicized portion :

> When the wealthy Ellicott family built a flour mill not far from his farm, Banneker befriended George  *Ellicott. Ellicott’s knowledge* about science and astronomy impressed him.

The choices are :

> Which choice most effectively combines the sentences at the underlined portion?
>
> A) Ellicott of whom
>
> B) Ellicott, from whom his
>
> C) Ellicott, whose

I know that obviously the best is the last choice, but still can't figure out strong reasons to say that A and B CAN'T work

Comment: We do not normally say "knowledge about" general fields of study such as science and astronomy. We normally say "knowledge of". In fact "knowledge about" even specific things is quite rare. We might just say that someone had "extensive knowledge about computers in the early 1950s" say, but "knowledge of" would be more common even in that context.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use "of whom knowledge" because the possessive formed by "of" follows the noun possessed.

> his dog = the dog of him

is grammatical although not highly idiomatic.

> of him the dog

is simply not grammatical. Word order is important in English.

"From" simply does not show possession.